# CSS Responsive Web Design: Do min-width and max-width change between landscape and portrait on tablets?

Tags: responsive-design, tablet, landscape-portrait, css

I am modifying a website's CSS to make it responsive. I'm ready to start throwing media queries all over the place, but something occurred to me:

When you turn a tablet to switch it from portrait to landscape mode or vice versa, does the 'width' attribute that media queries run off of ("min-width", "max-width", etc) change?

This'll help me figure out whether I need to write twice as many sets of just how many sets of variant CSS I need to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it changes. The browser will always render content according to the display width, unless you've told it not to.